# A Web Part or Web Form Control on this Page cannot be displayed or imported. The type could not be found or it is not registered as safe

Tags: 2013, list, migration, 2003

We migrated the Sites from SharePoint 2003 to SharePoint 2013. In SP2013 when we clicking on some of the lists we are getting the error

> "A Web Part or Web Form Control on this Page cannot be displayed or imported. The type could not be found or it is not registered as safe."

We checked in SP2007 and SP2010 and it is working fine.

Issue is only on SP2013,can any one help on this, why we are getting this issue?

Comment: Have you customized the list views? Or check the page and make sure there is no custom code running under.